# Delete 30 lines of file every loop

Tags: python

I want to delete the 30 lines that I print in a loop, for example, I have a file that contains 500 lines, and I can only loop 30 lines through it once. I want to remove the 30 lines that I already looped and then loop on the other lines (30 everytime).

How can I do that ?

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
    for i, word in zip(range(30), words):
        # remove 30 lines from file
```

Comment: Quick and dirty way I can think of right now is to read the remaining lines after your 30 lines into a string, write them to the file and then read the lines of the new file again.

Comment: Or do I misunderstand? Do you want to remove the 30 lines from the file on disk or only your `words` variable?

Comment: Do you literally want to rewrite the file in each iteration? That seems horribly inefficient. A common and efficient solution is to just leave the file handle open and continue reading where you left off until you reach the end of the file. Of course, if you need to keep track of your position across reboots etc you need something more sophisticated and robust.

Comment: @LouisCloete From the disk, overwrite it.

Comment: @tripleee I already tried to write the file in each iteration and my computer crashed. I will try this thanks.

Comment: @user14005342 ok then the easiest should be to read 30 lines, read the rest and write the rest you read to the same file name.

Comment: You'd probably un-indent your for loop, because you really don't need to wait until it is done before you close the file handle. The for loop shouldn't need to be inside the with block. That should take care of the crash as well.